# How to get salt bucket count in Apache Phoenix?

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-phoenix

Apache Phoenix recommends [salted buckets](https://phoenix.apache.org/salted.html) for improved performance. I wish to get the count of salted buckets for a table I created some time ago.

- The SQLLine based client doesn't offer anything similar to a MySQL `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- Also Hbase `describe` command doesn't give any information on the `SALT_BUCKETS`.

How can one get the count ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select table_name, salt_buckets from SYSTEM.CATALOG where salt_buckets is not null;
```